# Replace youtube embed iframe by video ID - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace some youtube iframes by something like a bbcode. Example:

**Sample content:**

> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
>   ipsum
>
> [iframe width="560" height="315"
>   src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RbJjC98ArCI" frameborder="0"
>   allowfullscreen][/iframe]
>
> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

- note that I needed to replace the characteres < AND > BY [ AND ] or the iframe code wouldnt be shown.

**The content replaced:**

> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
>   ipsum
>
> [youtube]RbJjC98ArCI[/youtube]
>
> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

**Javascript sample code:**

```
var content_with_bbcodes=content.replace(SOME_REGULAR_EXPRESSION_HERE, '[youtube]$1[/youtube]');
```

I would also like the inverse. A regular expression to convert the bbcode to iframe...

Someone here experienced about regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that should work.

```
var content_with_bbcodes=content.replace(/\[.+?embed\/(.+?)\".+\]/, '[youtube]$1[/youtube]');
```

As for the inverse, it's doable but you'll have to add the width and the height.

```
// sample
var height = 100;
var width = 200;
var content_iframe=content_with_bbcodes.replace(/\[youtube\](.+?)\[\/youtube\]/,'[iframe height="'+height+'" width="'+width+'" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen][/iframe]');
```